# Adding a multiple of the identity into a generalized eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

Consider the generalized eigenvalue problem 
$$ Av = \lambda M v$$ 
where $A$ is symmetric positive semi-definite and $M$ is symmetric.

What happens to $\lambda$ if I add a multiple of the identity to $A$, i.e. if I instead solve $$ (A + \zeta I)v = \tilde{\lambda} M v $$
then how are $\tilde{\lambda}$ and $\lambda$ related?

---

**Context**: I need to perturb $A$ (which is symmetric positive *semi*-definite) to make it positive definite, so that I can use a particular numerical solver on $Av=\lambda Mv$. However, if I add $\zeta I$ to $A$, then I need to know how to correct the resulting eigenvalues. I also wonder whether I could perturb $M$ as well (without breaking its symmetry) to simplify the issue.

The closest question appears to be [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2782721/effect-of-adding-a-constant-to-the-diagonal-of-the-right-matrix-on-the-eigenvalu), though it is slightly different and unanswered.

The most I can really show is that $$ \zeta M^{-1}v=(\tilde{\lambda}-\lambda)v $$
which merely says that $M$ does have an effect on the magnitude of the perturbation of $\lambda$.

Comment: Can't you add the same multiple $\zeta I$ to both $A$ and $M$?

Comment: @joriki Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to help. I end up with $\lambda M v = (\widetilde{\lambda}M + \widetilde{\lambda}\zeta I - \zeta I)v$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I hadn't thought that through. You could add multiples of $M$, but of course that won't help if $M$ isn't positive definite and you need $A$ to be positive definite. Another idea: Could you find the null space of $A$ and project it out?

Comment: Dear @joriki, thanks for your response. However, I am not sure what you are suggesting exactly (merely my own ignorance). Are you saying to remove the null space of $A$ via the SVD rank-$k$ approximation and solve the system with that as $A$ instead? Then perturbation is not needed?

Comment: Yes, you could do it using SVD, though I wasn't specifically thinking of that. Whatever means you have of finding the null space of $A$, you could transform to a basis in which the null space and its orthogonal complement are spanned by separate parts of the basis, and then you could only deal with $A$ and $M$ restricted to the orthogonal complement.